# Create two apps from one (using targets?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an objective c project in Xcode wherein i must have two apps with complimentary functionality.  For convenience I have written all of my functionality inside one app but now I need to really separate this into two distinct apps.  My question is about how to go about creating the second app.  Should I just duplicate the Xcode project folder and make my changes there?  I've also read a little about targets.  Is that a potential solution to this?

Comment: what all did you try till now?

Comment: C and Objective**-C** are different languages. Please show your effort and a specific question. This is neither a tutorial site, nor will we solve your overal problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it sounds like adding another target to your existing project is the way to go for what you're trying to achieve. This article might prove useful to you: https://itexico.com/blog/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code

Comment: Or you can create a framework common to two projects (depending on the separation degree of your apps).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, target is the way to do it.

Useful link to understand what it is:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends how the two apps will differ. If the GUI will be very similar then different targets would do.
But if you want flexibility to change the GUI of each app by big amounts then you could create separate projects but put common model functionality into a library which is linked to by the different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve it by following approachs

1. Adding a new Target and reusing the code and resources
2. Or create a framework in a generic way and pull all the reusable codes and resources in that, through this you only need to drag and drop the .framework file in any of you current or future models. 
   I suggest go with framework